# When did Kirk time travel before the events of The Voyage Home?

Tags: star-trek, time-travel, star-trek-tos

In the movie *Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home*,

> McCOY: Are you really going to try this time travel in this rust bucket?
>   KIRK: **We've done it before.**
>   McCOY: Sure, slingshot around the sun. If you pick up enough speed you're in time warp. If you don't, you fry.

What is Kirk referring to when he says "We've done it before" ?

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Slingshot_effect

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Tomorrow_is_Yesterday_(episode)

Comment: Related, possibly a dupe: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/181266/12857

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The technique was first employed in the TOS episode [*The Naked Time*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122429/does-the-naked-now-refer-to-any-particular-tos-episode) but not involving the sun.  They used it again (off camera) in *Tomorrow is Yesterday*.  (The first one where they came back to the 1960s.)  Also in *Assignment: Earth*, where they encountered Gary Seven.

Comment: Looking at the question title, Kirk time-travelled via *other* means as well: In *The City on the Edge of Forever* (via the Guardian) and in *All Our Yesterdays* (via the Atavachron). But obviously, the slingshot is what they're referring to in the question's dialogue...